# SQL Server Select into Specific DataFrame Format

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-2.7, pandas

I have a table that contains the columns Date, Identifier, and Price e.g.

```
| Identifier |   Date   | Price |
|------------|----------|-------|
|    693477AA|1990/10/31|    100|
|    353477ZB|1991/08/31|    101|
|    123457ZB|1992/08/31|    105|
```

I'm using pandas [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) function to grab the data from a SQL Server database. Either using SQL or pandas DataFrame functionality I need to get the data into the following pandas DataFrame format.

```
           693477AA     353477ZB     123457ZB
Date           
1988-1-1        NaN          NaN        99.41
1988-1-2     100.54          NaN        98.11
1988-1-3      99.45          NaN          NaN
```

**So that there is a (possibly Null) price entry for every DISTINCT Date in the table. For the set of Identifiers satisfying a condition.**

Right now I have it working with a for loop,

```
data = []
identifiers = "SELECT DISTINCT Identifier FROM TABLE WHERE [Condition]"
for id in identifiers:
    data.append("SELECT Date, Price FROM TABLE WHERE Identifier=[id] ORDER BY DATE")
pandas.concat(data, axis=1)
```

However this only works for very strict [Condition] since the table is quite large (>3M rows).

**How can I implement SQL, DataFrame manipulation, or a combination of both to achieve the desired format?**

Thanks.

Comment: Why use a loop to query the db?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we can use [pivot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) function:

```
In [144]: df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Identifier', values='Price').rename_axis(None, 1)
Out[144]:
            123457ZB  353477ZB  693477AA
Date
1990/10/31       NaN       NaN     100.0
1991/08/31       NaN     101.0       NaN
1992/08/31     105.0       NaN       NaN
```

or [DataFrame.unstack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
In [149]: df.set_index(['Date','Identifier'])['Price'].unstack('Identifier')
Out[149]:
Identifier  123457ZB  353477ZB  693477AA
Date
1990/10/31       NaN       NaN     100.0
1991/08/31       NaN     101.0       NaN
1992/08/31     105.0       NaN       NaN
```

or [crosstab()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
In [154]: pd.crosstab(index=df['Date'], columns=df['Identifier'], 
                      values=df['Price'], aggfunc='first') \
            .rename_axis(None, 1)
Out[154]:
            123457ZB  353477ZB  693477AA
Date
1990/10/31       NaN       NaN     100.0
1991/08/31       NaN     101.0       NaN
1992/08/31     105.0       NaN       NaN
```

or [pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
In [156]: df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='Identifier', values='Price', fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, 1)
Out[156]:
            123457ZB  353477ZB  693477AA
Date
1990/10/31         0         0       100
1991/08/31         0       101         0
1992/08/31       105         0         0
```

PS if you prefer to "pivot" data on the SQL Server side - please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can using `groupby`.

```
df.groupby(['Identifier','Date'])['Price'].sum().unstack('Identifier')
```